# Jenkins + Artifactory in Red Hat

Tags: docker, jenkins, redhat, artifactory

Good morning, I have a server with Red Hat Enterprise 7.6 (it can only be this one) installed and I have to install jenkins + jfrog artifactory.

The easiest way to do this would be with docker or installing them on the machine? The docker I already installed them but I do not know which is the most correct way to use them.

The docker seems to me better in the matter of I need to have other tools in that server and everything in container. In the future this machine will also have gitlab.

Thank you for your help

Comment: not a good approach to install all the applications on a single server. Instead they should be separated across multiple hosts. and the installation mostly rpm's to be used. but docker-compose is very handy tool that can be used as well.

Answer (score 2):

Docker Compose will be your best option and is the [recommended option](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+with+Docker) from JFrog's point of view for the scenario you're describing. We've added a bunch of examples of docker-compose scripts to our [GitHub repos](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-docker-examples/tree/master/docker-compose/artifactory) that should give you a great start.

Answer (score 0):

You can user docker-compose tool.
Combine all required services in one yaml file.